# PHPにおけるGET,POSTでのUndefined index: nameエラーについて

Tags: php, form

よろしくお願いします。

PHPにてformタグを生成し、input,submitで送ったデータを同ページで反映させたいと思いましたが、うまくいきませんでした。

以下、状況です。

`test.php`ファイル

```
<form name="name" action="test.php" method="GET">
    <Label for="name">氏名:</Label>
    <input name="name" type="text">
    <input type="submit" value="送信">
</form>

<pre>
<?php

echo htmlspecialchars($_GET["name"]);

?>
</pre>
```

*htmlやbody等のタグは割愛しております。

同ページで氏名欄に任意の氏名を記述して送信を押すと、`Undefined index: name`エラーが発生してしまいます。

調べると`test.php`に初回アクセスした際に`($_GET["name"]);`が未定義のため発生するエラーらしく、
対策として

```
if (!empty($_POST["submit"])) {}
```

もしくは

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {}
```

を用いての定義確認をする

という旨の記事がありましたが、そもそも本文中において`$_GET["name"]`の定義とは何を指しているのでしょう。

`form`から送られた情報のタグ内には`name="name"`にて定義済み`GET`変数で`"name"`を取得できるのかと思いましたが、
別途定義の必要性があるのでしょうか。

恐縮ですが、アドバイスいただけますと幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

注意していただきたいのはエラーの内容としては未定義の変数ではなくて、
未定義の配列indexを参照しているということです。

自作の配列の変数の存在しないキーにアクセスしようとすると、同様のエラーになります。試してみてください。

通常は自作の配列の変数であればindexを宣言すれば済むのですが 、

`$_GET`はPHPで定義されるグローバルスコープな配列の変数のため宣言することができず、質問中のように存在するかチェックしてから使う必要があります。

> そもそも本文中において$_GET["name"]の定義とは何を指しているのでしょう

ということで
ここは`$_GET`の配列のキーの定義を指しています。

Comment: ありがとうございます！ どうやら、サーバーの設定の関係かうまく取得できなかっただけのようです。 恐縮ですが追加で質問させていただきたいのですが、根本的な話で、
if(isset)やif(!empty)で$_REQUEST等でform情報を取得して任意の行動(関数の呼び出し等)を
行う意味合いでif(isset)やif(!empty)が存在するのはわかるのですが、それ以外にこれらのif文を使用する
シチュエーションなどありうるのでしょうか。 抽象的な質問で恐縮なのですが、他にもfilter_input関数などの用途がどのような状況で使用されるのか印象がわかなかったので質問させていただきました。 趣旨違いなので、無視していただいて構わないのですが、お答えいただけると嬉しく思います。

Comment: 渡される配列が場合によってキーがないような状況も発生することはRQUEST以外ではほとんどないです。例えばレガシーなコードではDBの結果を配列でもらっていたり、何らかのメソッドの結果を配列でもらっていたりします。があまり使いどころはないかもしれないです。